# Vite server does not inject tailwind when initializing from not root directory

Tags: tailwind-css, vite, preact

I have Preact application that is running on Vite server.

This is my `vite.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import * as path from 'path';
import preact from '@preact/preset-vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [preact()],
    base: './',
    build: {
        outDir: '../resources/cef',
        emptyOutDir: true,
        minify: 'esbuild',
        reportCompressedSize: false,
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src') },
        ],
    },
});
```

I have postcss.config.cjs:

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    }
}
```

And tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {},
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
}
```

This is the way I initialize the application in development mode:

```
npx vite ./ --clearScreen --host=localhost --port=3000
```

But for my needs I need to initialize the application from another directory (src-cef is preact root dir)

```
npx vite ./src-cef --clearScreen --host=localhost --port=3000
```

And as I run the app in first way (from root directory) everything works fine, but if I declare path manually tailwind doesn't get injected, CSS are not loaded and I am getting following warning

```
  VITE v4.5.0  ready in 865 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:3000/
  ➜  press h to show help

warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

I tried to declare tailwind.config.js path in vite.config.ts but nothing happened.

Comment: `content` file globs could be relative the the directory you start Vite in. Try editing the `content` file globs to be relative to the `src-cef` directory.

Comment: @Wongjn Can I run the command to act like I am performing command from root dir? It breaks much more things as for example won't initialize `@apply border-border;` from shadcnUI, many things are getting broken if running out of root dir.